# create animation inside a method

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a method named compare image, its compare face between saved file and face by camera capture ,

sometimes it will take long time ,to process it ,
i wish i can use a animation like loading bar,or maybe i can use a .gif file
until all process is finished

this is example my code

```
 def compareimage(id):
    try:
      loadimage()
      compareimage()
      insertlogintodatatabase()
      savelogimage()
    except:
      exception()
```

i wish i can create an animation during all this process ,

how can i create it?

enter code here

Answer (score 0):

Didn't quite understand what you mean by 'animation' because it can mean multiple things. If you are trying to create a **Progressbar** in tkinter, then import **tkinter.ttk** and you are good to go! The code for a determinate progressbar:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
prg = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='determinate')
prg.pack(pady=20)
# You can use the start function to animate the progress bar just give it an int to determine the speed!
prg.start(10)
# You can also use the two lines below to add to the progress bar's value
# prg.step(5)
# prg['value'] = 50
root.mainloop()
```

Also you can set the mode to 'indeterminate' and then start the progress bar which may be what you want. If you are talking about custom animations then that is a bit different. If
you want to make a custom progress bar in tkinter then you should use the **Canvas** widget. Example of a custom progress bar in tkinter using canvas:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.config(bg="black")
percent = 0
progress = None
canvas = Canvas(root, width=310, height=10, bg="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="black")
canvas.pack(pady=10)
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 0, 300, 6, fill="#2C383E", outline="#2C383E")


def animate():
    global percent, progress
    if percent < 100:
        percent += 1
        if progress is not None:
            canvas.delete(progress)
        progress = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 0, percent * 3, 6, fill="#3333ff", outline="#3333ff")
    # Remove these two lines (the elif statement) to make the progress bar 'determinate'
    elif percent == 100:
        percent = 0
    root.after(5, animate)


# You can just call the function or assign it to a button
# animate()
btn = Button(root, text="Fill! ", command=animate)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```